# Rego write a test for every entry with a condition has to have another condition

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

Example data:

```
{
    "serviceA_primary": {
        "foo": 1
        "bar": 2
    },
    "serviceA_secondary": {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 3
    },
    "serviceB_primary": {
        "bar": 2
    },
    "serviceB_secondary": {
        "bar": 3
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to write a test that for every key with serviceA in the name, it's `bar` value matches with the `bar` value of the corresponding serviceB.

For example, `serviceA_primary.bar == serviceB_primary.bar` and `serviceA_secondary.bar == serviceB_secondary.bar`

Honestly don't really know how to approach. I was planning on filtering out `serviceB` and then for every `serivceA` do something. But I don't think it's the right approach.

```
deny_due_to_mismatch[res] if {
    some key, val in input
    res := {k: v |
        regex.match(`serviceA`, key)
        k := mpkhs_coord_name
        v := mpkhs_coord_info
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; This logic is simple to express using the `every` keyword (which you can enable with `import rego.v1`). For example:

```
every_serviceA_is_valid if {
    every name, value in service_a {
        value.bar == service_b[name].bar
    }
}
```

To make this happen, I defined two helper rules `service_a` and `service_b` that generate maps containing the respective services, keyed by the suffixes (e.g., `"primary",` "secondary"`, etc.)

```
service_a[x] := value if {
    some name, value in input
    startswith(name, "serviceA_")
    x := substring(name, count("serviceA_"), -1)
}

service_b[x] := value if {
    some name, value in input
    startswith(name, "serviceB_")
    x := substring(name, count("serviceB_"), -1)
}
```

There is duplicated logic here, however, if there will only ever be `serviceA` and `serviceB` then I think this is fine. On the other hand, if you want to generalize the logic you could write a function that returns a map of services for a given name/prefix. For example:

```
services(name) := {key: value |
    some k, value in input
    prefix := sprintf("%v_", [name])
    startswith(k, prefix)
    key := substring(k, count(prefix), -1)
}
```

Then you could use the function like so:

```
every_serviceA_is_valid_v2 if {
    every name, value in services("serviceA") {
        value.bar == services("serviceB")[name].bar
    }
}
```

Here's a full example in the playground: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/53Hh2wU2Uh

Comment: Ahh I see the helper functions is a good idea, makes it very to implement!